# Why can't i use current of and returning into in one sql command in plsql?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

I tried update book's price with cursor and update sql command. I used current of and returning into in one update command and error occured: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

I had to change my update and i wrote id = id_zet. It fixed it, but i don't understand, why below code is wrong. Therefore my question is: Why can't i use current of and returning into in one sql command in plsql?

```
  SET serveroutput ON;
  DECLARE

  CURSOR books IS 
  SELECT title, id_publisher
    FROM book
    FOR UPDATE OF price;
  price book.price%TYPE;
  id_zet publisher.id%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT id INTO id_zet FROM publisher WHERE company_name = 'Zet';
    FOR k IN books LOOP
      IF k.id_publisher = id_zet THEN
        UPDATE book SET book.price = 1.1*book.price WHERE CURRENT OF books RETURNING book.price INTO price;
      ELSE
        UPDATE book SET book.price = 1.05*book.price WHERE CURRENT OF books RETURNING book.price INTO price;
      END IF;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(k.title || ' ' || price);
    END LOOP;

  END;
```

Comment: Tried to find you a good reason, but this was all I could find (comment by Dragon): http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1380163

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the only reason is because Oracle haven't implemented it.  In your case it's easy enough to work around.

```
DECLARE

    CURSOR books IS 
      SELECT title, id_publisher, price
        FROM book
        FOR UPDATE OF price;
      price book.price%TYPE;
      id_zet publisher.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT id INTO id_zet FROM publisher WHERE company_name = 'Zet';
    FOR k IN books LOOP
      IF k.id_publisher = id_zet THEN
        price := k.price *1.1;
      ELSE
        price := k.price *1.05;
      END IF;
      UPDATE book 
       SET book.price = price 
       WHERE CURRENT OF books ;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(k.title || ' ' || price);
    END LOOP;
 END;
```

Doing a Row-By-Row update in a CURSOR LOOP like that isn't a particularly efficient way of working.

You could replace it with

```
  UPDATE book 
  SET book.price = price * decode(id, id_zet, 1.1, 1.05);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this one working? According Oracle it does exactly the same:

```
CURSOR books IS 
 SELECT title, id_publisher, ROWID as aROW
   FROM book
   FOR UPDATE OF price;
 price book.price%TYPE;
 id_zet publisher.id%TYPE;

BEGIN
   SELECT id INTO id_zet FROM publisher WHERE company_name = 'Zet';
   FOR k IN books LOOP
     IF k.id_publisher = id_zet THEN
       UPDATE book SET book.price = 1.1*book.price WHERE ROWID = k.aROW RETURNING bookprice INTO price;
     ELSE
       UPDATE book SET book.price = 1.05*book.price WHERE ROWID = k.aROW RETURNING book.price INTO price;
     END IF;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(k.title || ' ' || price);
   END LOOP;
END;
```